# Filtering data in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have got series of data that contains some objects in one array(json file) and it will be shown by react.

```
 class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
 super(props);
  this.state = {
   data: [],
       .
       .
       .
currentPage: 1,
itemsPerPage: 20,
value: '',
filterTerm: null,
startIndex : 0,
endIndex : 4,
    }}}

[{'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc25', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Korston Hotel Moscow'}},{'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc24', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Lavanta Hotel'}},{'id': '5c0b6cd9e1382352759fbc28', 'hotelinfo': {'hotelsearch': {'realname': 'Stanpoli Hotel'}}]
```

There is a paging which displays 4 pages by default and show the rest of pages by clicking next button.

```
render() {
    const { data, currentPage, itemsPerPage, startIndex, endIndex } = this.state;
    const indexOfLastItem = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstItem = indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage;
    const currentItems = data.slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem);
    const renderHotel = currentItems.sort((a, b) => a.total - b.total).filter(this.filterData).map((item, i) => {
        return <div class="item">
            <span>{item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname}</span>
        </div>
    });
    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(data.length / itemsPerPage); i++) {
        pageNumbers.push(i);
    }

    const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map(number => {
        return (
            <li className={(this.state.currentPage === number ? 'active ' : '') + 'controls'}
                key={number}
                id={number}>
                {number}
            </li>
        )
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange} class="hotelName" />
            <span onClick=this.handleSearch} class="searchbtn">search</span>
            { renderHotel }
            <ul id="page-numbers" class="pagenumDef">
                <li onClick={this.decremant} class="nexprev">
                    <span class="fa-backward"></span></li>
                {renderPageNumbers}
                <li onClick={this.increment} class="nexprev"><span class="fa-forward"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div >
    )
};
```

I have an input(class="hotelName") which user start to type in (e.g user type 'Korston' ) and click a button and new result should just contain the data of hotels those contain 'Korston' name.

```
handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
}
handleSearch = () => {
    let inputval = this.state.value
    const { value } = this.state;
    this.setState({ filterTerm: value });
}
filterData = (item) => {
    const { filterTerm: term } = this.state;
    if (term === null) {
        return true;
    }
    let inputval = this.state.value
    inputval = term.toLowerCase()
        .split(' ')
        .map((s) => s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
        .join(' ');

    let realname = item.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname
    let len = realname.length
    if (len !== 0) {
        if (realname.includes(inputval)) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The main problem is that every time I am filtering only the current page, it means that I filter the paginated result. I should first filter list then paginate the filtered list but how can I do it?

Comment: I would probably implement two lists - one which is the original, un-filtered list of items and another which is the filtered list which you paginate and display. When the user changes the filter parameters you update this second list from the first. Both lists can exist in the state. Perform the filter (make the filtered list from the unfiltered list) when you update the state in the `handleSearch` and not in the render.

Comment: Thanks @madebydavid for your answer. I tried to change code to this one : const renderHotel = data.sort((a, b) => a.total - b.total).filter(this.filterData).slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem).map((item, i)=> {
   return .......})

Comment: To filter all the list, then slice the filtered result.But does not work!

Comment: Can you show me what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some insights.

You can try to do filtering by `searchTerm` firstly and then do transformation due to pagination purposes.

I've created a little demo for you right here https://codesandbox.io/s/xl66vov1o4

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter data with this.state.value before slice example:

```
var targetData = data;
if (this.state.value) {
  targetData = data.filter((d) => d.hotelinfo.hotelsearch.realname.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.value.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
}

const currentItems = targetData.slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem);
```

Comment: Thanks @Faust. But there is this error :"targetData" is read-only.

Comment: You are right a have changed const to var it should remove error